# Woocommerce single product page Hook customization

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I am a beginner at PHP but I have basic in web development,

I have the following code  at `content-single-product.php`

```php
        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
         */

        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
```

and when I am trying to add a new action to Hook in the single product page

I customized this section to be as the following

```php
        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
         */
         function carzyFunction(){
                echo'<h1>crazy statement</h1>';
            }
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'carzyFunction', 15 );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
```

what I can't understand is that, although assign the `carzyFunction()` priority of 15, it appears at the end of the single product summary section,

why it didn't show up between price section and product description section

[image: crazy function output appears at the end of the single product summary]

Comment: You don't have to add that piece of code to the template file, add it to your theme's `functions.php` file instead

Comment: yes, you are right, I did it before with another function, you can notice the [ you save 7% ] badge, I added it throw `functions.php`, but although I assign the priority to be 15 it appears at the end too, so I managed to add it at the first with the priority [1], otherwise, it didn't go right

Comment: Depending on the theme you use, small adjustments may indeed be necessary. So your question has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'njengah_text_after_price' );
function njengah_text_after_price($price){
    $text_to_add_after_price  = echo'<h1>crazy statement</h1>';;
          
    return $price .'<br>'.  $text_to_add_after_price ;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.